# Signal handler question

Tags: c, linux, signals

We've been covering signals in C/Unix, and the professor gave an example in class that is confusing me.  In the main method below, the signal function is called with the included arguments.

```
main()
{
  signal(SIGALRM, handler);   // install handler
```

handler is a function defined as `static void handler(int param){`

According to the Ubuntu `man 7 signal`, SIGALRM is an integer value 14, and handler is a programmer defined function.  However, the integer parameter is not explicitly defined in the signal call, so how does the handler recieve the argument?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help.  The real problem that tripped me up was that the class hasn't covered typedefs so I didn't know how it was incorporated into the function, and that was the piece that was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the previous comments answered your question or not.  I'm guessing you're asking *how* the parameter gets to the signal handler. If so:

Every signal handler **must** have the same signature.  It's hard-coded into the kernel that signal handlers will take a single int parameter and have no return value.  You don't tell the kernel -- via `signal()` -- how to call the handler, because you have no choice in the matter.  When the kernel decides to call your signal handler, it already knows what signal it wants to send.  So it looks up the address of the handler, and then calls that function like

```
(*pointer_to_handler) (signal_number);
```

as Paul's answer says.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same handler function for several signals, so the handler is passed the signal value (e.g. `SIGALRM` = 14 in your case).

About the handler parameter, it is explicitely defined in the signature of `signal`:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

Comment: ok, so sighandler is an integer pointer to signum, in this case SIGALRM?

Comment: sighandler is a pointer to a function taking an integer as argument and returning void.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is declared in the declaration of the `signal()` function.

See the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal), it quotes the declarations from `<signal.h>`:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler will be called something like this:

```
     (*pointer_to_handler) (param);
```

The 'handler' you pass to signal is just a function pointer, not a call.  It is called later.

Answer (score 0):

The argument in question (`param` in your code) is the signal number (`SIGALRM`). It's not an additional parameter.