# How do I toggle debug mode in my program?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, signals

I have a project due soon about using signals and sighandlers and I'm essentially finished with it; however I am hung up on one part. Here is the part pasted from my teacher's prompt :    "...When it receives sigusr2 it should toggle into or out off a 
debug mode, e.g. if the debug mode is currently "on" it should 
turn debugging off, if debug is "off" it should turn debugging on.

When debugging is "on", your program should report the 
total every x seconds  and ignore sigusr1. 
When debugging is "off" the alarm should be turned off and your program 
should handle sigusr1 as before (i.e. report on the status of
total) ".

What exactly does he mean by toggle into debug mode? The only debug mode I am familiar with is the eclipse version. Asking another classmate, I got the response that I was suppose to build my own debug mode, also I am not sure what this means. Can anyone shed some light and point my in the right direction? Thank you for reading and thank you for help in advance!

Comment: And what was the response you got from your instructor? *That's* where you should first direct all questions about your assignments.

Comment: Ah of course. =)   Yes, I contacted him around noon today, but still no response (email), and unfortunately the deadline is at 11 pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about "debug" for a moment and just consider that your program needs to have two *modes*. While in one mode, it should behave a certain way, and in the other mode, it behaves a different way.

What's an easy way of keeping track of two states? A variable with two (or more) possible values, such as `bool`. So declare a global variable to keep track of whether you're in one mode or the other (but since using a global `bool` variable from a signal handler isn't technically supported, use `sig_atomic_t` instead):

```
sig_atomic_t in_debug_mode;
```

When you receive the signal that controls which mode your program should be in, change the value of the variable, and then make sure your program behaves in the way consistent with that mode. If you receive the signal and you're *not* in debug mode, then set `in_debug_mode = true`, set up your SIGALRM handler, and disable your SIGUSR1 handler. If you receive the signal and you *are* in debug mode, then set `in_debug_mode = false`, clear the SIGALRM handler, and set the SIGUSR1 handler.

The *name* of the mode is irrelevant. For the purposes of the assignment, it's called "debug mode," but it has nothing to do with the debugging features of any other program you might be familiar with.

Comment: I think this is undefined behaviour, though. You can only modify `sigatomic_t` inside a signal handler.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that your program keeps some state information about the debug level, like so:

```
int debug_level = 0;

void log(const char * message)
{
  if (debug_level > 0)
  {
    printf("Debug message: %s\n", message);
  }
}
```

Then you can say `log("starting loop");` or something like that in your program, and it will only be printed if the debug level is sufficiently high.

When you register the signal handler, you simply let it modify the global `debug_level` variable. (Make sure to use type `sigatomic_t` for the variable though to ensure that you can safely modify it from within the signal handler!)

Comment: Ok, how does the debug_level get updated though? From here, it would appear to stay at 0 unless something external from the program is will modify it. =)

Comment: Your professor told you how this would be updated - via the signal SIGUSR2. Write a signal handler (as Kerrek said) that toggles the bit.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473645/signal-handler-question

Comment: @Derek: Do you also need help writing a signal handler? You should have said that in your question, or rather, make a different question, "how do I write a signal handler in C"?